# Помогите исправить ошибку: pyowm.commons.exceptions.NotFoundError: Unable to find the resource

Tags: python, telebot

```
from pyowm import OWM
import telebot

owm = OWM('3a8150ba7f6e4653d4e8358bedc1a3ce')
owm.config["language"] = "ru"

bot = telebot.TeleBot("2021079183:AAFIfk2B4YBWP4XNB-YN3TLzg0pkITUZfOA")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    observation = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather 
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]

    answer = "В городе" + message.text + "сейчас" + w.detailed_status + "\n"

    answer += "Температу сейчас в районе" + str(temp) + "\n\n"

    if temp < 10:
        answer += "Сейчас очень холодно оденься очень тепло"
    elif temp < 20:
        answer += "Сейчас холодно,оденься как потеплее "

    else:
        answer += "Температура нормальная одевайся как хочешь"

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer) 

bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Comment: Ошибки не решают. Ошибки исправляют.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Не вполне понятно, откуда в принципе взят объект класса OWM. Он что - встроен в модуль telebot? Или какой-то модуль импорта (pyowm.OWM, скажем) вырезан из примера?
2. Когда станет понятно, откуда взят класс OWM (что это за модуль/библиотека и какой версии) - надо курить его документацию и понимать, а как вообще оттуда достаётся температура. Если моя догадка верна, и речь о библиотеке PyOWM - то возможно, что вместо get_temperature() надо использовать просто temperature ().
   https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyowm.weatherapi25.html#pyowm.weatherapi25.weather.Weather
   Ну и дополнительно покурить примеры из
   https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v3/code-recipes.html

P.S. Такое чувство, что вы ключи к OWM и своему боту тут в паблик выложили - пожалуйста, не надо так. Привыкайте перед постингом кода проверять его на наличие чувствительной информации и заменять её на "xxxxx" / "*****" или любой другой символ или фразу.